# php exploding array in a loop and joining

Tags: php

Im using group concat to get concatenate the ids as uid
uid column is grouped as 68,94,97,88,93,69,95
 I want to refer other table and get the name of each id ,for that i explode                      the                       array         as     given below

How do i get the `$arrurtype` in the `$row` array ?

```
    $rs = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT A.* ,    
   GROUP_CONCAT( `B`.`uid` ) AS `uid`
       FROM A
        JOIN B
          ON A.id = B.id
       GROUP BYA.Section_Id  limit $offset,$rows");
  $items = array();   
          $i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rs))
       { 
        $idSysUsers = $row->idSysUsers;    
     $exp =  explode(',',$idSysUsers);  
      foreach($exp as $val)
          {
        $qUTdd = "SELECT  uname from users where  `uid = '".$val."'";     
    $q11 =  mysqli_query($dbc,$qUTdd);      
     $rrr = mysqli_fetch_object($q11);
        $arrurtype[] = $rrr->uname;
       }     


$row = array(   
 'cola1' =>$row->a1,
'cola2'=>$row->a2,
    'cola3'=>$row->a3,
    'cola4'=>$row->a4,
'cola5'=>$arrurtype
  );   
    array_push($items, $row);
  //$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the ids in comma separated format, you will need to use `IN` To get all the users in these ids. instead of looping as many as users you have!!

now `$rrr` will have all the users you have asked for.

```
    $idSysUsers = $row->idSysUsers;
    $usersnames = "SELECT  uname from users where  `uid IN ('".$idSysUsers."')";      
    $q11 = mysqli_query($dbc,$qUTdd);
    $rrr = mysqli_fetch_object($q11);
```